# Chain Snackbar calls

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-snackbar

I'm trying to use the snackbar on Android Compose. However, as I'm trying to display 2 messages in a row on the snackbar, I can only see the first message, does anybody know what can cause this?

I'm putting the code involved below:

Component code related to Snackbar:

```
/*
    The state is hoisted. It contains the snackbar message that is not null if
    there is something to display
*/

state.snackbarMessage?.let { resourceId ->
    val message = stringResource(resourceId)
    viewModel.handleEvent(
        AuthenticationEvent.SnackbarMessage(
            message = message,
            type = when {
                state.isFailure -> SnackbarType.ERROR
                else -> SnackbarType.VALIDATION
            }
        )
    )
}

/* Custom Component using Scaffold to host snackbar events */

Frame(
    modifier = modifier,
    snackbarState = viewModel.snackbarState,
    onShowSnackbar = { viewModel.onSnackbarDisplayed() }
) { innerPadding ->
    // UI Content
}
```

Frame Component:

```
@Composable
fun Frame(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    header: @Composable () -> Unit = {},
    snackbarState: StateFlow<MajorSnackbarData?>? = null,
    onShowSnackbar: (() -> Unit)? = null,
    content: @Composable (PaddingValues) -> Unit
) {
    val coroutineScope = rememberCoroutineScope()
    val scaffoldState = rememberScaffoldState()

    val showSnackbar: (MajorSnackbarData) -> Unit = {
        coroutineScope.launch {
            onShowSnackbar?.invoke()

            scaffoldState.snackbarHostState.showSnackbar(
                message = it.message,
                actionLabel = it.type.name,
            )
        }
    }

    snackbarState?.collectAsState()?.value.also { data ->
        if (data != null) {
            showSnackbar(data)
        }
    }

    Scaffold(
        modifier = modifier,
        topBar = header,
        scaffoldState = scaffoldState,
        snackbarHost = {
            SnackbarHost(it) { data ->
                MajorSnackbar(data)
            }
        },
        content = content,
    )
}
```

ViewModel base that hosts Snackbar:

```
open class BaseViewModel : ViewModel() {
    private val _snackbarState = MutableStateFlow<MajorSnackbarData?>(null)
    val snackbarState: StateFlow<MajorSnackbarData?> = _snackbarState

    protected fun showSnackBar(
        message: String,
        type: SnackbarType = SnackbarType.ERROR
    ) {
        _snackbarState.value = MajorSnackbarData(message, type)
    }

    open fun onSnackbarDisplayed() {
        _snackbarState.value = null
    }

}
```

Event handling in a viewmodel:

```
fun handleEvent(event: Event) {
    when (event) {
        // ...
        is Event.SnackbarMessage -> displayError(event)
    }
}

private fun displayError(event: Event.SnackbarMessage) {
    showSnackBar(event.message, event.type)
}
```

Comment: What is `state.snackbarMessage`? What updates its value? ViewModel?

Comment: It is a resourceId for the string resource to display, it is updated from the viewmodel via the state

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a very simple way of handling snackbars that I always use in my projects. You can directly create a `SnackbarHostState` in the ViewModel itself and show snackbars directly from the ViewModel.

```kotlin
// ViewModel
val snackbarHostState = SnackbarHostState()

fun doSomething() {
    ...
    // If you need to show a snackbar here, directly call the showSnackbar function
    snackbarHostState.showSnackbar(
        message = // Your message,
        actionLabel = // Your action label,
    )
}

// In your composable
val scaffoldState = rememberScaffoldState(snackbarHostState = viewModel.snackbarHostState)

Scaffold(
    modifier = modifier,
    topBar = header,
    scaffoldState = scaffoldState,
    snackbarHost = {
        SnackbarHost(it) { data ->
            MajorSnackbar(data)
        }
    },
    content = content,
)
```

This will give you a lot more control over the snackbars. If you need to display two snackbars one after the other, just place the two calls together in the viewModel.

```kotlin
snackbarHostState.showSnackbar(
    message = message1,
    actionLabel = actionLabel1,
)
snackbarHostState.showSnackbar(
    message = message2,
    actionLabel = actionLabel2,
)
```

Note that because `showSnackbar` is a suspend function which suspends till the snackbar is visible, the second snackbar will appear only after the first one has gone.